# How to debug nfsrootfs not booting issue

Tags: linux-networking, nfs4, arm

We have Beaglebone black based custom board with 4GB eMMC and 256MB RAM.
We use network boot for putting software on eMMC for very first time.

For this purpose we have configured ubuntu PC for network boot(tftp and nfsrootfs). It acts as tftp and nfs server.

Now with one of the board we are seeing that board is getting IP but it doesn't complete booting i.e. it doesn't go execute `busybox-init` and we don't even see console on the tty line.

Same thing works with other boards.

I am able to ping the board. so kernel is running but it is stuck and not able to mount network rootfile system.

I don't know how to debug this issue from here.

Failed board Kernel log after which I don't see anything

```
[    5.385958] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[    5.405936] Sending DHCP requests ., OK
[    5.616404] IP-Config: Got DHCP answer from 192.168.2.1, my address is 192.168.2.175
[    5.624814] IP-Config: Complete:
[    5.628254]      device=eth0, hwaddr=7c:38:66:69:dd:95, ipaddr=192.168.2.175, mask=255.255.255.0, gw=192.168.2.1
[    5.638996]      host=192.168.2.175, domain=custom, nis-domain=(none)
[    5.645785]      bootserver=192.168.2.1, rootserver=192.168.2.1, rootpath=
[    5.652858]      nameserver0=8.8.8.8
[   60.326388] PM: request_firmware failed
```

Working board kernel log where I see VFS mounts root on nfs

```
[    5.376053] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[    5.396024] Sending DHCP requests ., OK
[    5.436489] IP-Config: Got DHCP answer from 192.168.2.1, my address is 192.168.2.10
[    5.444909] IP-Config: Complete:
[    5.448352]      device=eth0, hwaddr=a0:f6:fd:36:58:2e, ipaddr=192.168.2.170, mask1
[    5.459093]      host=192.168.2.170, domain=custom, nis-domain=(none)
[    5.465881]      bootserver=192.168.2.1, rootserver=192.168.2.1, rootpath=
[    5.472956]      nameserver0=8.8.8.8
[    5.483342] VFS: Mounted root (nfs filesystem) on device 0:12.
[    5.489971] Freeing unused kernel memory: 216K (c0597000 - c05cd000)
init started: BusyBox v1.20.2 (2018-01-05 08:41:27 EST)
starting pid 656, tty '': '/etc/init.d/rcS'
Starting rngd
Setting timezone and system clock: [OK]
Starting rsyslogd: [ OK ]
rsyslogd already started; not starting.
Starting Watchdog.
Starting ntpd: [OK]
starting pid 720, tty '/dev/ttyDefault': '-/bin/sh'


BusyBox v1.20.2 (2018-01-05 08:41:27 EST) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

#
```

any pointers debugging techniques to debug this issue ?